# Why does `Box<dyn Sink>` not implement the `Sink` trait when using Tokio and the experimental async/await support?

Tags: async-await, rust, rust-tokio

I am having a play with async/await by using Tokio with the async/await feature enabled in my `Cargo.toml` (and the latest Rust nightly with 2018 edition):

```
tokio = { version = "0.1.11", features = ["async-await-preview"] }
```

I've run into an error I don't understand, which is reproduced in this minimal example:

```
#![feature(await_macro, async_await, futures_api)]
use tokio::prelude::*;

pub fn main() {
    tokio::run_async(async {
        let s: Option<Box<dyn Sink<SinkItem = u8, SinkError = ()> + Send + Sync + 'static>> = None;

        if let Some(sink) = s {
            await!(sink.send_async(100));
        }
    });
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> (dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 'r): futures::sink::Sink` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     tokio::run_async(async {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'r> futures::sink::Sink` is not implemented for `dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::sink::Sink` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `tokio_async_await::sink::send::Send<'_, std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send>>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1> {std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 'r)>>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 's)>, tokio_async_await::sink::send::Send<'t0, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 't1)>>, ()}`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:5:28: 11:6 for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1> {std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 'r)>>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 's)>, tokio_async_await::sink::send::Send<'t0, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 't1)>>, ()}]`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:5:28: 11:6 for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1> {std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 'r)>>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 's)>, tokio_async_await::sink::send::Send<'t0, std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::sink::Sink<SinkItem=u8, SinkError=()> + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 't1)>>, ()}]>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
  = note: required by `tokio::async_await::run_async`
```

and it goes away if I remove the line beginning "await!".

When using Tokio without the experimental async/await support, my program is happy with the idea that a `Box<dyn Sink>` is a `Sink`, so I'm not really sure why the error crops up using async/await stuff.

What does the error mean? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to wrap the `Box`ed `Sink`s into a newtype and implement the `Sink` trait on that. I think that perhaps `Box<dyn Sink>` does not implement `Sink` in this nightly, which is basically what the error message implies (I guess the async/await shims redefine `Sink` and don't implement it on `Box`).

My wrapper ended up looking like this:

```
struct BoxedSink<I, E>(Box<dyn Sink<SinkItem = I, SinkError = E> + Send + Sync + 'static>);

impl<I, E> Sink for BoxedSink<I, E> {
    type SinkItem = I;
    type SinkError = E;

    fn start_send(
        &mut self,
        input: Self::SinkItem,
    ) -> Result<AsyncSink<Self::SinkItem>, Self::SinkError> {
        self.0.start_send(input)
    }

    fn poll_complete(&mut self) -> Poll<(), Self::SinkError> {
        self.0.poll_complete()
    }
}
```

You have to wrap your `Box<Sinks>` in this to make them once again implement `Sink`.

Comment: Based on chatting with some of the implementors, it sounds like `Sink` is not an abstraction that is going to continue to exist in the new futures world. You can tell it hasn't been updated because it still has the split `Item` / `Error` associated types, unlike `Future` and `Stream`.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting to know. I am maybe a bit surprised that Stream would continue to exist but not Sink (piping Streams to Sinks seems useful for instance, though easy with async/await I guess!), but Sink does feel like the least useful of the abstractions to keep around!